# Writing and reading LocalDateTime from file most efficiently

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

What is the fastest way to write `LocalDateTime` instance to file and then read it from file and convert it back to `LocalDateTime` object?

I used to save milliseconds and then convert it to `Date` object. It looked pretty fast but now I am dealing with Java 8's `LocalDateTime` and it's not clear what would be most efficient way to save and retrieve it from file.

I don't think using `DateTimeFormater` is a good idea as it requires more resources to convert it to `String` and then parse the `String`.

Time zone is not relevant.

Comment: _"What is the fastest way... "_ - Wrong question.  The right question is _"Is my current way of doing things causing a performance problem?"_.  If not, spend your time on other more important things and come back to this only when you can show that it is a bottleneck.

Comment: Old Date was used for many things that now in java 8 has their own clases. You really mean LocalDateTime or Instant? If the second tou can do exactly the same as before but using the methods getEpochMilli() and ofEpochMillis()

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the milliseconds and timezone is not important, you can use the `java.time.Instant` class - with only the `LocalDateTime` there's no way to get the milliseconds, because this class has no timezone/offset information.

```
// get the current date
Instant instant = Instant.now();

// get milliseconds (equivalent to java.util.Date.getTime())
long millis = instant.toEpochMilli();

// get Instant from milliseconds
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis);
```

---

If you have a `LocalDateTime`, though, you can easily convert it to an `Instant`:

```
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.now();
Instant instant = d.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();
```

This code obviously assumes that the values in the `LocalDateTime` correspond to an UTC date and time. To convert the `Instant` back to a `LocalDateTime`:

```
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

---

PS: have you measured your system's performance to know if "fast" is really an issue? Anyway, I'm doing things the "standard" way (the most straightforward way based on what the API offers), is that what you want?

Maybe you can think that creating an `Instant` as an "intermediary" object makes things less "fast" (but you'll need to measure that anyway). If that's the case, you can get the millis from the `LocalDateTime` directly (assuming that it corresponds to a date and time in UTC):

```
// get the current date
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.now();
// get milliseconds value
long millis = d.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC) * 1000 + d.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND);

// get LocalDateTime from millis
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(millis / 1000, (int) (millis % 1000) * 1000000, ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

It's important to note that `java.time` classes have nanoseconds precision, so getting the milliseconds makes you lose this precision.

If you don't want to lose the nanoseconds precision and don't necessarily need to work with the millis value, you can store 2 different numbers (**epoch day** and **nano of day**):

```
// get the current date
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.now();

// get values from LocalDateTime
long epochDay = d.toLocalDate().toEpochDay();
long nanoOfDay = d.toLocalTime().toNanoOfDay();
// save both values to file

// retrieve the LocalDateTime from the values
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.ofEpochDay(epochDay), LocalTime.ofNanoOfDay(nanoOfDay));
```

This doesn't require the conversion to UTC, but it requires 2 numbers instead of one. You might think that creating a `LocalDate` and a `LocalTime` makes things slower, but these 2 objects are **always** created internally by `LocalDateTime` (in all cases).

Not sure, though, if all this math is "faster" enough than using an `Instant`. It's a matter of testing to see which one is best for your case.

But for me, the most "efficient" in terms of clarity and code-easy-to-maintain is using an `Instant` (or using the last approach of **epoch day** and **nano of day**). And unless you're dealing with millions of records, I'm not sure if that'll really be a performance issue.

---

I've made a simple test (run each case above 10 million times), and the last approach (using **epoch day** and **nano of day**) seems to be the fastest. But the difference is less than 1 second. Only by running 2 **billion** times I've got a 20-seconds difference, so if you're dealing with this many records, maybe it's worth it.

Regarding other resources (memory usage, CPU, I/O), I didn't check. But anyway, performance issues are very specific to each environment: depending on how the system is designed, how the system's parts/modules/components interact with each other, and many other factors, you can have different bottlenecks in each situation.

In the end, you'll have to test each approach and see which one performs best in your system. Or you can conclude that it doesn't make a significant difference (and for cases with less than a couple of millions records, maybe it doesn't - but you'll only know after benchmarking it).

Comment: does this answer the question *What is the fastest way to write LocalDateTime instance to file and then read it from file and convert it back to LocalDateTime object?*

Comment: @ScaryWombat Well, that was the fastest way I could think ok. Anyway, I've added more insights to the answer. Not sure if that's what the OP wants, though...

Comment: *Not sure if that's what the OP wants, though* That's for sure, me too

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer. I should have been more clear what I meant by 'fastest'. I need to find way to read and write LocalDateTime to and from file that would require least computing resources

Comment: @user3930989 Maybe (probably) the best alternative is the last one (using epoch day and nano of day) - it seems to create less temporary objects. But I believe you'll have to test all approaches and see if it makes a difference. I've made very simple tests (run each approach 10 million times) and the last one (epoch day/nano of day) seems to be fastest, but the difference is less than 1 second. Regarding the resources required (memory, I/O), I didn't check, but I believe the difference would also be small - anyway, you'll have to test each one and see it makes a difference in your system.

Comment: @user3930989 I've also tested with a formatter and it's more than 10 times slower, compared to the approaches above (so I don't think it's worth mentioning in the answer).

Comment: @user3930989 Anyway, I've updated the answer with my tests.